# Let $F$ be the set of onto functions $f: A \to A$. Is $F$ under composition operations form a Group?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

So the $F = \{f:A\to A\,|\, f$ is surjective$\}$. And since $f$ is surjective $R_{f}=A$.
To $F$ be a group following should be satisfied,

1. **Closure**
   Suppose $f_{1}: A\to A$ and $f_{2}:A\to A$. Then $f_{1}\circ f_{2}: A \to A$ and $f_{1}\circ f_{2}$ is onto. So $f_{1}\circ f_{2} \in F$ satisfied.
2. **Associativity**
   $f_{1}\circ(f_{2}\circ f_{3}) = (f_{1}\circ f_{2})\circ f_{3}$
3. **Identity**
   $\exists g\in F \:\;\;\forall f\in F\:$s.t $f \circ g = g \circ f = f$
4. **Inverse**
   $\forall f \in F \:\: \exists h\in F$ s.t $f \circ h = h \circ f=g $
   I don't know whether $2, 3,4$ are True or False. How to show that they are true or false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property 2 is true because it's true for composition of functions. And restricting our attention to some particular type of functions can't change that. (Well, as long as all compositions are well-defined, but your proof of this set being closed under composition takes care of that.)

Property 3 is satisfied here because the identity map belongs to this set of functions $F$. (Do you see why?)

The tricky one is property 4. And that depends on the underlying set $A$. If $A$ is finite, then being surjective is equivalent to being bijective, and so each function in $F$ has an inverse in $F$. But if $A$ is infinite, this is not true anymore.

Comment: Now I see that the property 2 is correct. And I understand the Property 4 is true. (I thought about it using pigeon hole principle). But I don't see why property 3is true ?

Comment: First of all, property 4 is not necessarily true: it's only true if $A$ is finite, and not true if $A$ is infinite. For property 3: does the identity map (the function $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in A$) belong to $F$? In other words, is it true that the identity map is surjective?

Comment: Yeah, it should be surjective. Identity map, maps each element of $A$ to to the same element of $A$. So it is surjective. Hence it is in $F$. Am I correct?

Comment: @Nimantha: Yes, that's correct.